# JSON.Net - Select without knowing the name

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got the following json:

```
    {
   "success":1,
   "return":{
      "29460691":{
         "amount":0.391199,
         "rate":0.00608
      },
      "29460690":{
         "amount":0.285893,
         "rate":0.00607,
      },
      "29460689":{
         "amount":0.322908,
         "rate":0.00606,
      }
}
```

And want to find the first *rate* of a certain *amount*. So let's say I want to select the *rate* of the first order with the *amount* of "0.285893".

How can I best make this with Newtonsoft? My biggest problem is selecting the number within JsonObject["return"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *`Dictionary<string, SomeObject>`* .

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);

public class RootClass
{
    public int Success { set; get; }
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Return { set; get; }
}

public class Data
{
    public decimal Amount { set; get; }
    public decimal Rate { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect this worked wonders, I knew you could deserialize them to an object but didn't know the dictionary<string, data> would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDictionary <string,JToken> json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Now you can access the keys of dictionary, which are same in your JSON.